# Reading in integer from stdin in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, stdin

I have the following piece of code where I take in an integer n from stdin, convert it to binary, reverse the binary string, then convert back to integer and output it.

```
import sys

def reversebinary():
  n = str(raw_input())
  bin_n = bin(n)[2:]
  revbin = "".join(list(reversed(bin_n)))
  return int(str(revbin),2)

reversebinary()
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "reversebinary.py", line 18, in <module>
  reversebinary()   
File "reversebinary.py", line 14, in reversebinary
   bin_n = bin(n)[2:] 
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

I'm unsure what the problem is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are passing a string to the `bin()` function:

```
>>> bin('10')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

Give it a integer instead:

```
>>> bin(10)
'0b1010'
```

by turning the `raw_input()` result to `int()`:

```
n = int(raw_input())
```

Tip: you can easily reverse a string by giving it a negative slice stride:

```
>>> 'forward'[::-1]
'drawrof'
```

so you can simplify your function to:

```
def reversebinary():
    n = int(raw_input())
    bin_n = bin(n)[2:]
    revbin = bin_n[::-1]
    return int(revbin, 2)
```

or even:

```
def reversebinary():
    n = int(raw_input())
    return int(bin(n)[:1:-1], 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to convert the input to an integer not a string - it's already a string. So this line:

```
n = str(raw_input())
```

should be something like this:

```
n = int(raw_input())
```

Answer (score 1):

It is raw input, i.e. a string but you need an int:

```
bin_n = bin(int(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

`bin` takes integer as parameter and you are putting string there, you must convert to integer:

```
import sys

def reversebinary():
  n = int(raw_input())
  bin_n = bin(n)[2:]
  revbin = "".join(list(reversed(bin_n)))
  return int(str(revbin),2)

reversebinary()
```