# how to remove the runtime (NZEC) error in my python code?

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the prime generator problem PRIME1 in spoj.com but getting runtime error(NZEC). The problem needs to take a number of test cases and for each test case, it needs to input two numbers in a line for each different test case and then finally print the output as the prime numbers in the range of each number
The error is Runtime error time: 0.01 memory: 7736 signal:-1

```
    # your code goes here

def is_prime(x):
    if x<2:
        return False
    if x==2:
        return True
    for y in range(2,x):
        if x%y==0:
            return False
    return True
t=int(raw_input())
mylist=[]

for i in range(0,t):
    a=raw_input()
    a=a.split(' ')
    mylist.append(int(a[0]))
    mylist.append(int(a[1]))
k=0
while k<len(mylist):
    c=mylist[k]
    k+=1
    d=mylist[k]
    k+=1
    for z in range(c,d+1):
        if is_prime(z):
            print z
    print
```

Comment: What function is `list.amount()` ? I have never heard of any such function for a list.

Comment: You should add the Error you get

Comment: Man, `is_prime` sure runs often, doesn't it? And each time, it checks every blasted number under the number to be checked? With no memoization? Maybe there's a [faster way to check for primes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n)?

Comment: @AnandSKumar It was a mistake. Can you notify me the reason am getting this error.

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe am running the code on ideone.com and the error i am getting is Runtime error time: 0.01 memory: 7692 signal:-1 . Can you point out the mistake?

Comment: @SiddharthPanigrahi nope. It was just a review comment. I mentioned it, so that you can do this in your next questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is `raw_input()` returns string , not integer. But you are trying to use it directly in your `range()` function - `for i in range(0,t)` . `range()` function only accepts integers as arguments, so you need to convert your input into `int` before using in range.

```
t=int(raw_input())
```

Comment: It's still showing error: Runtime error time: 0.01 memory: 7736 signal:-1

Comment: I changed to 't=int(raw_input())' and updated it above

Comment: Doesn't error out for me, what are you giving as input?

Comment: I am running the code on ideone.com and it's showing runtime error and not allowing me to provide any input!!

Comment: when you are using ideone.com you have to provide the input before running the program (there is an option to provide input into the stdin) , provide complete input there . Its not an interactive interpreter, you cannot provide input on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

On running this on python 2.7.9, I found that there is only one error that you are using `t` in `range(0, t)` but `t` is string here, because our `raw_input()` method reads input and returns string. That raises in Python parlance. To remove this we should have to type cast the input we got. Like, t = `int(raw_input())`.
And this will result in t as an integer.

For info about raw_input() follow: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

For reading integer in python you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867405/reading-in-integer-from-stdin-in-python) post on stackoverflow.